# python __divide list to multiple list based on ordered sequence of numbers

Tags: python, numbers, logic

I have this list
nums=[1,2,6,7,8,9,44,90,110,111,112]

I want to divide them into sub lists based on sequence

44 : there is no number before and after ;Excluded

90 same as 44

so the final output will be

finall_lst=[[1,2],[6,7,8,9],[110,111,112]]

I want that list to be dynamic so that it can receive any number of items even millions

thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? What results did you get? This looks like a school assignment, and Stack Overflow is not meant for other people to solve your problem, but rather to help you when you get stuck

Comment: You could use one of the solutions in the duplicate and then filter the list based on the sublist length being greater than 1

Comment: I thought that  I do for loop for each item and at that item I thought to define variable which will plus 1 and if that equals it will append to another list and finally but It is hard to do in a code

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution to find group sequence from the list.

```
def groupSequence(x): 
    it = iter(x)
    prev, res = next(it), []
    
    while prev is not None:
        start = next(it, None)
        if prev + 1 == start:
            res.append(prev)
        elif res:
            yield list(res + [prev])
            res = [] 
        prev = start 

        
nums=[1,2,6,7,8,9,44,90,110,111,112]
print(list(groupSequence(nums)))
```

Comment: I got an answer ... based on the question which referred up in another page... I will try it when Iam free ... thanks for posting an answer ❤❤